# MongoDB score is irritating

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I am using MongoDB to store all kinds of Linux CLI commands (~ 15.000). Now I want to use the full text search to find the right command. Every command has a `name`, a short `description` and an explanation. I use weights in the index:

```php
$commandcollection->createindex(
  ['$**' => 'text'],
  [
    "weights" => ["name" => 3, "description" => 2],
    "name" => "textIndex",
    "default_language" => "english"
  ]
);
```

When I now run the search the score of the results is irritating:

```php
$results = $collection->find(
  [
    '$text' => [
       '$search' => $searchPattern,
       '$language' => 'english',
       '$caseSensitive' => false,
    ]
  ],
  [
     'projection' => ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']],
     'limit' => 10, 'sort' => ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']]
  ]
);
```

In this example the search query `phar file decompress` is literally the desciption of the second document, but the score is lower then the one of the first document.

[Screenshot of MongoDB results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlDc0.jpg)

What is wrong here? Is it the search string that is not searching for `and` but `or`?